# Hide all opened sibling elements on click

Tags: jquery

In my menu, I want to show only `ul`-s which are active. Meaning if I click a different link, the previously active element should be hidden. In my example below, if `Item-1` is active and I click on `Item-2`, the `Item-1` should be hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#main-menu').on('click', function (event) {
    $(event.target).parent().children('ul').toggleClass('hidden');
    $(event.target).parent().children('ul').addClass('is_open');
    $('#main-menu').toggleClass('is_closed');

    if ($(event.target).parent().children().length <= 1) {
      $('#main-menu .is_open').toggleClass('hidden');
      $('#main-menu ul').removeClass('is_open');
      $('#main-menu').addClass('is_closed');
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.sm ul {
  display: block;
}

.sm .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="main-menu" class="sm sm-simple">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1-1</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1-1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1-1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1-1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">Item 2-1</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2-1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2-1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2-1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just toggle `$(this)` and hide siblings [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/724/)

```js
$('#main-menu > li > a').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.hidden').toggle();
  $('#main-menu > li > a').not($(this)).next('.hidden').hide();
})
```

You can also`toggleClass`[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/726/)

```js
$('#main-menu > li > a').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.hidden').toggleClass('active');
  $('#main-menu > li > a').not($(this)).next('.hidden').removeClass('active');
})
```

For nested `ul` inside `li` you can do this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/x4hxxehd/16/)

```js
$('ul  li  a').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.hidden').slideToggle();
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
})
```

Comment: @Gabriel for that new example this is how code should look like (i also added some sliding) https://jsfiddle.net/x4hxxehd/15/

Answer (score 2):

**Changes made**

Added the below piece of code to hide all the `ul`

```
$('ul').addClass('hidden');
```

For optimisation purpose I used

`$('#main-menu .is_open').toggleClass('hidden is_open is_closed');`

`$(event.target).parent().children('ul').toggleClass('hidden is_open');`

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#main-menu').on('click', function (event) {
    $('ul').addClass('hidden');
    $(event.target).parent().children('ul').toggleClass('hidden is_open');
    $('#main-menu').toggleClass('is_closed');
    if ($(event.target).parent().children().length <= 1) {
      $('#main-menu .is_open').toggleClass('hidden is_open is_closed');
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.sm ul {
  display: block;
}

.sm .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="main-menu" class="sm sm-simple">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1-1</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1-1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1-1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1-1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">Item 2-1</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2-1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2-1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2-1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3-1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its good solution but when I add 3rd level, then I can't access it because the menu automatically closes itself. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gnemeth/x4hxxehd/14/

Comment: @Gabriel I was a bit busy. Anyway glad that you got the solution `:)`